# Laravel Convertir el valor de un array a Int

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas, necesito guardar en una variable el valor especifico de un array en otra variable

de aqui recibo los datos:

```html
 $data = \DB::select("
            SELECT 
                SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Por Despachar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Por_Despachar
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Planificado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Planificado
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Despachado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Despachado
            FROM presupuesto
        ");
Obtengo 3 valores por cada condicion
Quiero guardar el valor De planificado en otra variable es solo eso
```

```
$dta = [];
foreach($data as $d) {array_push($dta, $d);}
```

Obtengo esto:

```
array:1 [▼
0 => {#330 ▼
+"por_despachar": "4"
+"planificado": "1"
+"despachado": "0"
}
]
```

necesito algo asi

```
$intval1 = dta[1]; <--- guardar el valor especifico deacuerdo al indice
```

pero me da este Error:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

ejemplo entonces si dta[1] tiene como valor 5 y yo muestro muestro en pantalla $intval1 deberia mostrar:

```
5
```

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que no te funciona.

Comment: olvide colocar el error q me da, cuando coloco el indice 1 me da el siguiente error Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Si entiendo bien, ¿en `$d` tienes un array asociativo? Sería bueno ver que contiene `$data`

Comment: si no entiendo que sucecede si por ejemplo pongo el indice 0 me da todo el array de valores array:1 [▼
0 => {#330 ▼
+"por_despachar": "4"
+"planificado": "1"
+"despachado": "0"
}
] quisiera solamente el valor de Planificado

Comment: La verdad sigo sin entender lo que pretendes hacer, ¿podrías agregar los datos de entrada `$data` y el resultado esperado?

Comment: listo ya coloque los datos de entrada solo quiero guardar el dato de una de esas 3 condiciones por despachar, planificado o despachado en una variable mas nada me entiendes

Comment: Creo que _imaginas_ que tu array está de una forma, pero resulta que está de otra forma distinta. Lo confirma el hecho de decir: _no entiendo que sucecede si por ejemplo pongo el indice 0 me da todo el array_ No es que te de todo el array, sino que lo que tu crees que es todo el array en realidad no lo es, sino que hay otro nivel, o sea, en tu código has metido tu array dentro de otro array y por eso te muestra todo eso en la posición cero.

Comment: me ayudas a corregir eso necesito solo el valor entero

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien el problema, lo que te hace falta es especificar la llave correspondiente:

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
    array_push($dta, $d['planificado']);
}
```

Viendo tu consulta a la base de datos, no entiendo porque utilizar un `foreach()` si estás obteniendo unas sumas, por lo cual no creo que estés generando varios registros en `$data`.